# Is it possible to detect an AWS account is nearing the Lambda concurrency limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, concurrency, lambda

Lambda has some [concurrency limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) that when hit, cause subsequent invocations to get throttled.

This makes sense, but is it possible to detect this situation ahead of time and start applying backpressure?

The problem is that (according to the docs) the concurrency limit is per-account, which means a single runaway microservice can block ALL unrelated services.

For example: a lambda fn with an s3 event source could easily lead to API Gateway handlers being throttled and unhappy API users.

Is there any QoS for lambda functions?  It'd be great to be able to give public-facing functions priority.  (I know the answer is no, but I wish there were.)

Short of that, is it possible to detect that you're nearing this concurrency limit and build backpressure in?

I'm not seeing anything, and the only solution I can think of at this moment is to create a metric that [watches for Throttles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-functions-metrics.html) and as soon as one happens, toggle some flag somewhere?  This adds significant complexity though...

Any ideas?

Comment: I've spent a lot of time researching this and the short answer is it's not possible.  Additionally, the problem is far worse than I thought.  Consider the scenario of a developer testing a new lambda microservice that leads to throttles.  End-result: Your production lambdas also get throttled! Scary.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? Having to roll your own concurrency throttle is difficult and inexact, in my experience.

Comment: @LandonC Nope. They did end up rolling out per-function throttles you can implement that makes it slightly less scary. But that's not really a solution as much as some _there i fixed it_ duct tape. Because of this and some other obvious DoS problems with prod+dev being shared I always recommend everyone isolates at the account level.  IMO more granular control over auto scaling and concurrency is the last major cant-easily-workaround missing feature.

Comment: Yep, I totally agree. Per-function throttles don't mean much given the limits are at the region level. If you have multiple functions, you have no way of knowing the overall count without checking stats via API, and those are possibly 90 seconds behind.